# Position of the irrational numbers on the number line explanation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

To start off, I have a nice little discovery about the position of an irrational number on the number line.
Lets draw a straight line and divide it into ten equal parts (with red ink in this case to mark the equal parts) .
[image: Number line construction]

Now in each part, divide them into another ten equal parts.

[image]

Here the interesting thing is that if we keep doing the same process perpetually, the irrational numbers would never lie into the division mark (the red marks in the pictures). How is that happening ?

Comment: Well, because irrational numbers, along with the rational numbers that do not have a finite decimal expansion, aren't an integer multiple of any power of $10^{-1}$.

Comment: You cannot visually distinguish irrational and rational numbers since the rational numbers are dense in the set of real numbers that means no matter how close real numbers $a<b$ are togehether , there are still infinite many rational numbers $r$ with $a<r<b$

Comment: Welcome to some new knowledge of infinity. Look up Cantor's Diagonal Proof.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple. Any tick marks you're making are numbers of the form

$$\frac{n}{10^m}$$

for some nonnegative integers $n,m$.

This inherently make those tick marks rational numbers, at each and every stage.

Comment: Not just rational, but *decimal* too. Not all rationals even appear as red ticks.